# How does one set Kentico SiteContext.CurrentSite property values?

Tags: kentico-11

Where in the admin interface or configuration does one set the values of the API **SiteContext.CurrentSite** property? **grep**ping (well, actually **findstr**ing) the codebase and 30 minutes on Google has turned up nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the admin interface: **Applications** -> **Configuration** -> **Sites**, then click the edit icon (pencil)